# ASP.NET MVC Nuget Restore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I was wondering why is Nuget restoring needed? I mean nugets are just files that are downloaded to your solution. So if they are downloaded once why do they need to be restored sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

When you install a NuGet package to your solution/project, it does not add the files from that package to your solution/project. Rather it makes an entry to the csproj/project.json/packages.config (depending on the project type and VS version) on the required package dependency. And downloads the packages to the NuGet cache (not the solution).
When you build the solution, these packages are restored to the solution. Restoring means the packages (.nupkg) are expanded to individual assemblies and the exact dependency to these assemblies are written down in the assets file (project.assets.json) created in the obj directory. Again, here the files are not copied to the solution but instead are referenced from the cache. The build output will contains these files as required. Remember caching plays a big role into when the packages are actually downloaded vs. referenced from the cache.